# Изменение названия окна

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qt-designer

Столкнулся с проблемой, не могу найти способ изменить название окна и самой программы.

Я пробовал `MainWindow.setWindowTitle('New Title")` но это не помогло, не совсем понял что значит это в аргменте к функции - `const QString &`

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(600, 550)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(184, 183, 180);")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(165, -10, 270, 60))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Yu Gothic Light")
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.titleLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.titleLabel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 70, 80, 40))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Yu Gothic Light")
        self.titleLabel.setFont(font)
        self.titleLabel.setObjectName("titleLabel")
        self.titleLine = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.titleLine.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 120, 200, 25))
        self.titleLine.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.titleLine.setObjectName("titleLine")
        self.nicknameLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.nicknameLabel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(250, 170, 100, 40))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Yu Gothic Light")
        self.nicknameLabel.setFont(font)
        self.nicknameLabel.setObjectName("nicknameLabel")
        self.nicknameLine = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.nicknameLine.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 230, 200, 25))
        self.nicknameLine.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.nicknameLine.setObjectName("nicknameLine")
        self.passwordLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.passwordLabel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(250, 280, 100, 40))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Yu Gothic Light")
        self.passwordLabel.setFont(font)
        self.passwordLabel.setObjectName("passwordLabel")
        self.passwordLine = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.passwordLine.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 330, 200, 25))
        self.passwordLine.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.passwordLine.setObjectName("passwordLine")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(215, 410, 170, 50))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(59, 255, 0);\n"
"color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
"")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(405, 330, 25, 25))
        self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.pushButton_2.setText("")
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 600, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

        self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet("background-image: url(copyimg.jpg);")


    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-size:20pt;\">Password Generator</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.titleLabel.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-size:16pt;\">Title</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.nicknameLabel.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-size:16pt;\">Nickname</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.passwordLabel.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-size:16pt;\">Password</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Ваша проблема не понятна,  т.к. не видно ваших попыток  изменить название окна. Смотрим `setWindowTitle(const QString &)` - https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#windowTitle-prop Если будет не понятно, подробно расскажите что вы хотите сделать и что у вас не получается.

Comment: Я пробовал ```MainWindow.setWindowTitle('New Title")``` но это не помогло, не совсем понял что значит это в аргменте к функции - const QString &

Answer (score 1, accepted):

НИКОГДА НЕ ИЗМЕНЯЙТЕ код, сгенерированный Qt Designer, НИКОГДА. 
Создайте другой класс, который наследуется от соответствующего виджета, и используйте созданный класс для его заполнения.

[**windowTitle**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#windowTitle-prop) : QString

Это свойство содержит заголовок окна

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(600, 550)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(184, 183, 180);")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(165, -10, 270, 60))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Yu Gothic Light")
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.titleLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.titleLabel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 70, 80, 40))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Yu Gothic Light")
        self.titleLabel.setFont(font)
        self.titleLabel.setObjectName("titleLabel")
        self.titleLine = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.titleLine.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 120, 200, 25))
        self.titleLine.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.titleLine.setObjectName("titleLine")
        self.nicknameLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.nicknameLabel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(250, 170, 100, 40))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Yu Gothic Light")
        self.nicknameLabel.setFont(font)
        self.nicknameLabel.setObjectName("nicknameLabel")
        self.nicknameLine = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.nicknameLine.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 230, 200, 25))
        self.nicknameLine.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.nicknameLine.setObjectName("nicknameLine")
        self.passwordLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.passwordLabel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(250, 280, 100, 40))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Yu Gothic Light")
        self.passwordLabel.setFont(font)
        self.passwordLabel.setObjectName("passwordLabel")
        self.passwordLine = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.passwordLine.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 330, 200, 25))
        self.passwordLine.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.passwordLine.setObjectName("passwordLine")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(215, 410, 170, 50))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(59, 255, 0);\n"
"color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
"")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(405, 330, 25, 25))
        self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.pushButton_2.setText("")
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 600, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

        self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet("background-image: url(ball.png);")


    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-size:20pt;\">Password Generator</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.titleLabel.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-size:16pt;\">Title</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.nicknameLabel.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-size:16pt;\">Nickname</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.passwordLabel.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-size:16pt;\">Password</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.setWindowTitle('New Title')
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]